# Does /dev/stdin have input?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In Bash, I would like to use /dev/stdin.  As with many commands, stdin is optional though.  So, how would I know if I had stdin to read?  If there is no standard input, a command like `cat /dev/stdin` hangs waiting for input.

Here is my first attempt:

```
#Always says "no stdin"
if test -s /dev/stdin
then 
  echo stdin
else
  echo no stdin
fi
```

man test => -s FILE exists and has a size greater than zero

I guess the device file does not keep up with the available bytes.  It would be nice to do this in bash, `ssh` implements this functionality (in another language no doubt).

Comment: Difficult to understand what you hope to accomplish. Can you give us something besides `cat /dev/stdin`? You do know that in `echo text | cat` that `cat` is reading from its STDIN via the pipe mechanism while the echo has sent its text to STDOUT? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Asynchronous IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

Try [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) with `-t` flag. It will return after specified time even if there was no input to be read.

Comment: And `read -t 0`returns success (setting `$?` to 0) if input is available, failure otherwise, all without consuming the input.

Comment: `read -t 0` is just what I'm looking for.  I get the instant results so the script will be fast.

Fixed:
`
    read -t 0
    if test $? -eq 0
    then
      echo stdin
    else
      echo no stdin
    fi
`